# Google Cloud Storage JSON API Service account 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, json-api

I am trying to access Google Cloud Storage buckets objects with Java JSON API.

We are uses service account authentication. We also check our permission of service account ID as "Editor".

When we tried to list out bucket Object we got following error.

`403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}`

Authentication Code

```
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = null;
InputStream credentialsStream = null;
try {
  credentialsStream = new FileInputStream("<Location of Service Account JSON File>");
  credential =GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsStream, transport, jsonFactory);
} catch (IOException e) {

} finally {
  if (credentialsStream != null) {
    credentialsStream.close();
  }
}           


 if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all();
      credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
    }
return new Storage.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName("DemoApplication")
    .build();
```

Bucket Object Code

```
Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();

Storage.Objects.List listRequest = client.objects().list(bucketName);

List<StorageObject> results = new ArrayList<StorageObject>();
Objects objects;

// Iterate through each page of results, and add them to our results list.
do {
  objects = listRequest.execute();
  // Add the items in this page of results to the list we'll return.
  results.addAll(objects.getItems());

  // Get the next page, in the next iteration of this loop.
  listRequest.setPageToken(objects.getNextPageToken());
} while (null != objects.getNextPageToken());
```

Please help me out for this issue.

Comment: Did you get success on this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. I created service account with all IAM authorizations, created OAuth client for my service account, set scopes, but it dosent work -> I have an 403 error